# Import JSON file to JavaScript function

Tags: django

Is it possible to import a JSON file into a JavaScript function? If yes, how can this be done the best practice way?

Below is my code with a few json rows and It'd be insane to have a million rows hardcoded in the function.

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: try [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var availableTags = JSON.parse("{{ context|escapejs }}");
```

and then you can loop over normally in Javascript.

Check out the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpeQWp). It clearly works at the front end, the issue might be at the backend.

Comment: hmmm, ain't sure of that yet, here's my JSON file, items.json :(

Comment: @DonPislik Are you successfully passing the json from your view to your template? Try checking your json in your html first to see if it is working. {{ yourJsonSentFromView }}.

Comment: @DonPislik Check out the codepen, it demonstrates clearly that it works.

Comment: var availableTags = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('pathto/file.json')); will bring in the values from a file, but processing won't continue until the file is completely read and there's no error handling.